# ARP is showing same physical address for different IPs

Tags: networking, openwrt, arp

At home, I'm using WiFi to connect most devices with each other. My workstation does not have a WiFi adapter built-in, so I connected it via Ethernet to a WiFi router running OpenWRT in DHCP client mode that is associated with the nearest AP.

I generally have no problems with this setup at all, it's been working for a long time already.

There is something strange, though. When I try to see which computers are in the neighborhood by running `arp -a` from the workstation, it gives me a list of the various devices in my local network, each with their own IP address. But they all have the same Ethernet address. It's the address of the OpenWRT router my workstation is connected to.

Usually, that doesn't matter since I'm working higher up in the network stack. But sometimes it's necessary to communicate on the data link layer, such as sending WOL messages or do a data link layer broadcast, or get an IP address from an Ethernet address. All this would probably not work properly in this setup.

Is there anything I can do to to avoid this issue, maybe a configuration item in OpenWRT?

Comment: This sounds like the router is doing proxy ARP. That used to be popular, but it has some security vulnerabilities, and it is no longer recommended to have it enabled. You should find a way to disable it.

Comment: 14 views in a day.. not sure this was the right site, after all. ;) Proxy ARP is not enabled, I checked `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/proxy_arp`. I wouldn't know where else to look.